# Calling a webservice from a C# dll from within CLASSIC ASP

Tags: wcf, dll, asp-classic, wsdl

I'm a windows dev with very little knowledge of web applications and ASP. I'm trying to create a C# dll (which is making a webservice call) for someone, that is being called from a CLASSIC ASP app.

It all started from a WinForms test app that successfully loaded a WSDL and called that web service. Now the requirement is to take the test app functionality, move it to a dll and call that dll from the ASP app. I naively left the appconfig file there, and when that dll was called, he got this well known error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract Service1.MyService in the
>    ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found
>    for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the
>    client element.

I understand that classic asp doesn't have config files - I read a lot of posts about it, and most of the relevant ones mention to use BasicHTTPBinding and provide an endpoint address on the fly. How do I do that? Any examples?

I saw this answer:

> All I needed to do is to create a BasicHTTPBinding and provide an endpoint address on the fly.Then create a new instance of the web service using the created binding and endpoint address.

But i'm not sure how to do it.

This is the appconfig that worked for the winforms app:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://MyService.svc"
            behaviorConfiguration="custom" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyService.IMyService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>


  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="custom">
        <customInspector />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="customInspector" type="CustomBehaviors.CustomBehaviorExtensionElement, CompeteDataServiceTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>


</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure the service through code, as there is no config file in this case. See [Configuring WCF Services in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205277.aspx).